# Spammers can send their stuff even I have reCAPTCHA

Tags: recaptcha, spam

I have a huge problem with my reCAPTCHA! Spammers can send their ugly stuff even if I have reCAPTCHA "installed" on my website. I have created a own skin to reCAPTCHA and I have readed their wiki to make sure that I did everything right, but unfortunately something went wrong.

Here's how I have done it:

**Form**

```
    <!-- reCAPTCHA -->
    <div class="paddingbottom-5">
        <div style="border: 1px solid #d1d1d1; width: 300px;">
            <div id="recaptcha_image"></div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <!-- reCAPTCHA: Textfield -->
    <input type="text" name="recaptcha_response_field" id="recaptcha_response_field" tabindex="5">

    <!-- reCAPTCHA: Reload -->
    <a href="javascript:Recaptcha.reload()" class="noborder-link">
        <img src="'.ICON.'arrow-circle-double-135.png" alt="" class="image-icon-right">
    </a>

</div>
```

**Configuration** (is stored below the `require_once('configs/required/classes/class.recaptchalib.php');` in the same file as the form)

```
$response = recaptcha_check_answer(
    CAPTCHA_PRIVATE,
    IPADDRESS_NOHASH,
    $_POST['recaptcha_challenge_field'],
    $_POST['recaptcha_response_field']
);
```

`CAPTCHA_PRIVATE` contains my private key for reCAPTCHA which is linked to the right address (duh). `IPADDRESS_NOHASH` looks like this: `define('IPADDRESS_NOHASH', get_realip());`. The function "`get_realip()`" looks like this:

```
function get_realip() {
    if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])) {
        $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];

    } elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {
        $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];

    } else {
        $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    }

    return $ip;
}
```

I have also this function in JavaScript to apply my custom theme:

```
var RecaptchaOptions = {
    theme : 'custom',
    custom_theme_widget: 'recaptcha_widget'
};
```

I have made the class file for reCAPTCHA (class.recaptchalib.php) more prettier (it have now the same structure as the form structure, for an example) and I have also removed everything that belongs to the MailHide API because I don't use that API - only reCAPTCHAs API.

What's wrong? Have I missed something?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recaptcha is definitely not UNbreakable by spambots. I developed an OCR solution by my own within 12 hours from scratch and was able to break reCaptcha and the Yahoo-Captchas. (In Python, C and Java, using only third-party libraries for reading jpeg/gif/png.) Actually, it's an easy task, for a good programmer.

Anyway, reCaptcha will stop "beginners".

The best way to get rid of spam is to add some honey-pots to your website. Usually, this works the best. Of course, such a custom-solution takes a little time, but surely not longer than one day.

There are many (easy) tricks for honeypots, which you may find on Google. For e.g. hidden text fields (using css) and so on. In my case, I don't need captchas at all, since I added a bot-trap with a few lines of code.

Good luck! :)

Comment: Thanks! I will try to develop my own CAPTCHA :)

Answer (score 0):

1) I assume you have tested everything to ensure that when someone fails to enter a captcha that it properly denies the post/whatever?

2) You might try generating new keys as well.  It's possible your key has been compromised/broken and creating a new set may make the spam go away.

3) Having worked with a lot of recaptcha systems, eventually I end up turning it off and installing a better set of captcha questions that have easy answers for people likely going to your site if possible that would still be hard for spammers.  For example, if you have a site about "racing" then ask questions your users are likely to know, like "what is the driver's name that won the Indy 500 in 2011".  Yes, it's easy to research but whoever is behind the spam likely won't spend the time and most of your users will likely already know the answer.  After implementing similar question sets (and testing them!!!) on my systems my spam went to pretty much nothing.

Recaptcha is a great concept, but it appears not to be working much any longer.  Insert big sigh here...

Comment: **1**) I'm getting an error message that says that the CAPTCHA is wrong, if I mistypes or leave the field empty (I've been very careful to make it work). **2**) I'll check that :) Thanks! **3**) Oh. That's pitty :/ Maybe I must find another solution.

Comment: Good luck!  I hope you do find a better solution.